# Xamarin forms : Make a listener to know when a popup is closed or opened

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin forms. I am using this  pluging [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)  to use Popup

How can I make a listener in order to know when a pop up is opened and closed ?

To close a Pop up I use this code : `await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);`

To open a Pop up I use this code :

```
   await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YesOrNotPopup(){
    //some code here if i need 
})
```

;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

In your PopUp call:

```
    public void PopUpCall()
    {
      YesOrNotPopup PopUpYorN = new YesOrNotPopup();
      PopUpYorN.OnResult + = OnYNResult;

      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
          await RMSApplication.CreatePopupPage(PopUpAssinatura);
        });
     }

    private void OnYNResult(object sender, string e){
        //your logic
        //can you close or anything
    }
```

In your YesOrNotPopup:

```
  public partial class YesOrNotPopup: PopupPage
  {
    public event EventHandler<string> OnResult;
    ...
    
    private async void BtnYes_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    OnResult(this,"yes");
    }
  }
```