# Xamarin forms : Close a popup page automatically or when user press on background

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin forms and use the plugin [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage) for popup Page.

My problem : In my PopUp page file .NET. I would like to use the function `delayedWork()` to close the popup automatically only when the user hasn't pressed on the background for 10 seconds.

My code does not work because the function  `delayedWork()` is in  `OnAppearing()` function so if I click on background before 10 seconds it creates the error : `No Page in PopupStack` (because the popup is already closed)

Question : How to create a listener to know when a popup is Opened or closed , so that I know if I need to use the `delayedWork()` function ?

Here is my code :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    _ = delayedWork();
}



private async Task delayedWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    this.doMyDelayedWork();
}

private async void doMyDelayedWork()
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to detect when a popup is opened or closed, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944440/xamarin-forms-make-a-listener-to-know-when-a-popup-is-closed-or-opened).

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The issue that you are trying to pop on an empty stack: I used the following method in my Navigation helper to pop popups and it's never an issue :)

```
 public static async Task PopPopupAsync()
    {
        if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Count > 0)
        {
            await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

### Original answer

The reason this is not working is that you are forcing it to become Synchronous what you need to do is actually await your method so something like the below:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    catchasTappedToClose = true;
    await delayedWork();
}
```

Comment: @FreakyAly This still not working because if I tapped on backgroung the popup close but after the 10 seconds I get the error

Comment: Ah, now I understand your issue check my answer.